# Intellij Maven default annotation processors configuration getting lost

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, annotation-processing

I configured my `Maven` project to work with a `Annotation processor options` in IntelliJ Idea 2017.1 by adding two options that correspond to two `compilerArg` of `maven-compiler-plugin`.

My problem : IntelliJ reset the annotation processing configuration every time the `pom.xml` is modified. Is there any way to keep the configuration ?

Comment: Why do you want to use IntelliJ tooling exactly? Can't you keep using maven-compiler-plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with the new version of the Maven compiler plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=${mapstruct.defaultComponentModel}</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The previous configuration was

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <compilerArgs>
            <compilerArg>
                -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=${mapstruct.defaultComponentModel}
            </compilerArg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```